# jOOQ "EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM [field])" workaround?

Tags: sql, postgresql, jooq

There's syntax that allows transforming a Timestamp into various date parts, including the unix epoch. This works as follows (in lastest PostgreSQL at least):

```
SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM "ts") FROM...
```

However, jOOQ doesn't seem to support this syntax, as evidenced by [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jooq-user/IVy74kfg988/discussion) I found, which links to the still open [Issue #2132](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2132) on the jOOQ github.

What workarounds are there for this? How can I emulate this behavior within jOOQ's syntax (i.e. without having to write the entire query in pure SQL)?

Comment: if the problem is with `EPOCH` you can try extract `DAY` and multiply it by 60*60*24?..

Comment: I would lose a good bit of precision by that.

Comment: `(extract('DAY' from now()-'1970-01-01')*60*60*24 + extract(seconds from now())+ extract(minutes from now())*60 + extract(hours from now())*60*60)` gives exactly same as EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM now()) - see my answer?..

Comment: if you can use any functions, you could call `date_part('epoch', "ts")` instead (they are the same in PostgreSQL).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Workaround for jOOQ 3.10 and less

You can always resort to [plain SQL](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql/) with jOOQ:

```java
public static Field<Integer> extractEpochFrom(Field<Timestamp> field) {
    return DSL.field("extract(epoch from {0})", Integer.class, field);
}
```

#### Support in jOOQ 3.11 and more

There is currently (jOOQ 3.11) experimental support for additional, non standard `DatePart` types, such as [`DatePart.EPOCH`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql/). It might work already with PostgreSQL, but not with other databases.

This support will be improved in future versions, including jOOQ 3.12, see: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/7794

Answer (score 3):

Just wanted to add there's [`org.jooq.impl.DSL.timestampDiff(...)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#timestampDiff-java.sql.Timestamp-java.sql.Timestamp-) in case you needed the epoch to calculate difference between two timestamps in milliseconds.

Answer (score -1):

I'm sure there should be smth less monstrous then:

```
t=# select
  (extract('DAY' from now()-'1970-01-01')*60*60*24 + extract(seconds from now())+ extract(minutes from now())*60 + extract(hours from now())*60*60)
  -
  extract(epoch from now())
;
 ?column?
----------
        0
(1 row)

Time: 0.315 ms
```

Comment: 1: `extract()` has a special syntax, it cannot accept values before `from`, just identifiers. 2. `day` is day-of-month, i.e. it is `2` in case of `2017-02-02`, which is far from usable instead of `epoch`.

Comment: ah. I see - I thought it does not accept EPOCH only. Thank you

Comment: Just noticed, that you `extract` from an `interval`, which is generated by subtracting 2 timestamps. This is a special case, which generates an interval with maximum `days` resolution, so your formula could work. But usually it is dangerous to extract days from timestamp/interval, consider f.ex. `extract(day from interval '2 years 2 days')`

Comment: yes - this is why I summarize extract days*nnn extract hours*nnn etc

Comment: Ah, and 9.6 accepts the quoted syntax too (which is not standard, and older versions did not supported it, at least when I last tried it threw me syntax errors -- the docs still not state that it is accepted though).